# Should I seek explicit permission to place a logo into an image sprite with other logos?

Tags: logo, legal, client-relations, image-sprite

I'm currently trying to get permission to place various clients logos on a website, should I also ask for permission to place their logos into a image sprite together with other logos?

My reasons for concern stem a little deeper, because the various different clients could *loosely* be considered as competitors and the clients themselves may share that sentiment. The clients are all luxury retail outlets based in the UK, that's the most I can say. I have never heard of them being considered as competitors of each other, but I am aware that they have overlapping interests.

Additionally, by asking for permission to do this, I may bring something to their attention that they otherwise wouldn't have cared about.

On the flip side, a sprite sheet is just a technical means to an end, and no affiliations will be insinuated in their use together.

**So will they have grounds to cause a stink if I don't inform them that I'm using their logo in this way, even after they've granted me permission to use it?**

I know there aren't any/many lawyers here, I'm looking for a logical solution.

Comment: do you mean a sprite-sheet where each logo is displayed individually, but grouped "behind the scenes" for ease of loading/programming? or do you mean an image where all the logos are displayed at the same time?

Comment: If you have permission to display the logo, I don't know why I'd bother with complicating things by asking them to approve the particular technical implementation of showing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **So will they have grounds to cause a stink if I don't inform them that I'm using their logo in this way, even after they've granted me permission to use it?**

If they gave you permission to use it then the next question is did they ask for what. For example I needed 3 logos from companies so sent out requests --- one wanted to know more specifically what it was going to be for so I filled out their little permission form and stated trade show video. I wouldn't then put it on our website. I didn't get permission for that. The other two gave me broad usage permission for marketing purposes so I would put it on our website if I wanted to.

The most they could then do is basically ask me to take it down; which I would absolutely do if asked.

**update**

Look at the company's website, some very large companies may even have right on the site logos to download and guidelines on how and where it can be used.

If not then you should call the company up and tell them you're seeking permission to use the logo in some marketing materials and want to know who to speak with. They'll probably transfer you to someone in the company's marketing department. Discuss it with them as vaguely as possible to get the job done. I can't really give an example since I don't know why you're trying to show these logos. For my own reasons I said, "Hi, I'm putting together some materials to bring to trade shows and want to include your logo in some of our marketing since our product is compatible with yours." All three then asked me to email, two replied with permission and high res logos. The third replied with a formal request form that wanted a little more detail about its use and signature. I filled it out, emailed it over, and then that person emailed me over high res logos to use.

The three that I sent to are all competitors to each other, but compatible with our product (non-competitive with ours).

Comment: @Dominic I made an update for you